# Canine Physiology | Pomsky Vocalization - How Advanced For Speech?

Tags: dogs, training, vocalizations, communication, husky

There's been demonstration with some birds, such as with parrots like African Greys - e.g with Alex, with the work of comparative psychologist Dr. Irene Pepperberg, who also studied its intelligence using communication with Alex via vocalization), ravens and more.

I've also learned that huskies vocalize to some extent.

Questions by nicheness - higher number = less niche:

1. To what extent can huskies vocalize? Is there a research topic into this?
2. To what extent, preferably if also known maximally and minimally, can a **Pomsky** vocalize?
3. With vocalization, in some approximation, how much could a Pomsky communicate via speech?

I'm asking these questions because I'd like to get a general idea and don't know what research there is into communication via vocalization with Pomskies, that are also cross-breeds with Huskies (between that and Pomeranians) - hope this post/question isn't too wide-covering - please let me know if it is, and if so, I'll just post them as separate questions.

Comment: For my understanding: vocalization could be "two barks for yes, one bark for no"? Or do you speak about real "words"?

Comment: Could you add a few references to your post?

Comment: This kind of question has the potential to require several hours to find scientific material and write a meaningful answer. Before I even attempt it, I need you to clarify your question: Do you want to know how much human language dogs can understand? How many sounds that resemble human language dogs can produce? How close to producing comprehensible human language a dog can get (for example saying "walk" instead of simply whining at the door when they want to go out)? Otherwise all I can do is refering you to [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/) to do your own research.

Comment: I doubt that there’s extensive research done with a breed that isn’t considered as such but rather a designer dog?

Comment: @Stephie I assumed so, which is why I also asked about (pure) Huskies.

Comment: @Elmy it is if you're not knowledgable on the matter - I hope to get someone who is, instead of researching this information myself/asking someone to - however I appreciate you being willing to, so about what you asked:
I'm asking about how much human sounds Huskies, or more preferably, **Pomskies**, can produce, and be able to form into words, and preferably, if this was researched, know just how syntactic complexion they can express in one sentence - an advanced example is Stella from [Hunger for Words](http://www.hungerforwords.com) who can use 5 words in a sentences (so far, at least).